# JavaScript "classList" toggle is not switching an element's class name

Tags: javascript, popup, dom-events

I'm working on my JavaScript skills but I can't work this one out. I want to show an image in my body when the `button.terug` is clicked.

I tried using `classList.toggle()` to switch the class name `popup` from the `<img>` element on click but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

**JS:**

```
var uno = document.querySelector('button.terug');

var popup = document.querySelector('img.popup');

uno.addEventListener ('click', function(){
    popup.classList.toggle('img.popup');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="terug"></button>
<img class="popup" src="images/popup1.png" alt="beoordeling">
```

Comment: Is the script above the HTML? If so, the HTML doesn't exist when the JS runs.

Comment: It's not, I paste the code wrong but the JS is below the html

Comment: Right, it seems like the event does run, but the code doesn't do anything because there's no class called `img.popup` to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to toggle a class name **`img.popup`** on your **`.popup`** element class list instead of toggling the classname **`popup`**.

Change this:

```
uno.addEventListener ('click', function(){
    popup.classList.toggle('img.popup');
});
```

To this:

```
uno.addEventListener ('click', function(){
    popup.classList.toggle('popup'); // you don't need to add the dot since classList knows that the argument is a reference to a class-name.
});
```

---

Check and run the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the above code:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var uno = document.querySelector(".terug");
var popup = document.querySelector(".popup");

uno.addEventListener ('click', function(){
    popup.classList.toggle('popup'); // you don't need to add the dot since classList knows that the argument is a reference to a class-name.
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

img {opacity: 0;}
img.popup {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button class="terug">Click Me</button>
<img class="popup" src="images/popup1.png" alt="beoordeling">
```